# Revert to a newer version with Git

Tags: git

I am using Git (and versioning as a whole) for some weeks now, and even if it helped me increase my performance, I still didn't understand it all well.

So my question is : if I revert from a commit tagged version 0.6.3 of my project to an older commit (version 0.6.2, e.g.), is it possible to 're-revert' back to the newer commit of my project (version 0.6.3 in this example) ?

Comment: Please elaborate. What do you mean with "revert"? Do you mean "git checkout"?

Comment: What version are you talking about ? Is it a tag on your git repository ?

Comment: A newer version of what? Your project? If that's what you're talking about then the answer is almost certainly yes.

Comment: Sorry guys, I thought I was using the right terminology but obviously I am not. So I will update my question with more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible to revert reverts.

Depending on how the revert was performed on of the following options apply:

Using `git revert <commit/tag>`:
Simply revert the resulting commit via `git revert` again. Reverts executed via `git revert` are normal commits which simply “reverse” the commit, and obviously the reversal of a reversal is the original.

Using `git checkout <commit/tag> -- file`:
Simply checkout another commit. All commits are equal and git does not differentiate between older and newer ones.

Comment: Well, this is great. But I think the first thing I have to do is to get some software to manage my git repository. I'm using Netbeans' git  management system and I think I need to have more control to get all the benefits of Git. 
Again, thank you Sir :)

Comment: If you want absolute all abilites of git you should use the command line ;)